# Erlang and processes

Tags: multithreading, erlang, process, primes

I'm very new to Erlang and I'm currently reading Joe Armstrong's book, chapter 'concurrent programming'. I'm trying to run a  list of processes to calculate if a number is a prime (naive method). But my code runs as if there was no processes. Both methods have the same duration. Where am I wrong ?

shell.erl:

```
c(prime).

%a list of primes
NUMS=[102950143,102950143,102950143,102950143,102950143].

%time start
NOW1=now().
io:fwrite("Monothread~n").

%for each number test if it is a prime
lists:foreach( fun(N)->
    RESULT=prime:is_prime(N),
    io:fwrite("Result N=~p ~n",[RESULT])
    end, NUMS).
%display the duration
io:fwrite("Duration N=~p ~n",[timer:now_diff(now(),NOW1)/1.0e6]).

%time start
NOW2=now().
io:fwrite("Multithread~n").
%for each number, spawn a new process and test if it is a prime
lists:foreach( fun(N)->ProcId = prime:start(),
    io:fwrite("Calculating : procId=~p N=~p ~n",[ProcId,N]),
    RESULT=prime:is_prime(ProcId,N),
    io:fwrite("Result N=~p ~n",[RESULT])
    end, NUMS).
%display the duration   
io:fwrite("Duration N=~p ~n",[timer:now_diff(now(),NOW2)/1.0e6]).

halt().
```

file prime.erl:

```
-module(prime).
-export([start/0,is_prime/1,is_prime/2]).
%run the forever_function
start()->spawn(fun forever_function/0).

%catch the queries
forever_function()->
    receive
        { From,Number} -> From! is_prime(self(),2,Number),
        forever_function()
    end.

%monothreaded function
is_prime(Number)->is_prime(self(),2,Number).

%multithreaded function
is_prime(ProcessID,Number)->
    ProcessID ! {self(),Number},
    receive
        RESULT->RESULT
    end.

%recursive function scanning all the numbers from 2 to Number
is_prime(ProcessID,Div,Number)->
    if
        Div =:= Number -> {{number,Number},{prime,true}};
        Number rem Div =:= 0 -> {{number,Number},{prime,false}};
        true-> is_prime(ProcessID,Div+1,Number)
    end.
```

Thanks,

Pierre

Comment: this question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697959/why-doesnt-this-erlang-code-work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your lists:foreach call in the second block, you are calling `RESULT=prime:is_prime(ProcId,N)`, which is doing a `receive` for the result.  So, you're spawning a process and then waiting for it to finish until you spawn the next process.  That's why it takes the same amount of time as the single-threaded approach: both ways, you're only doing one at a time.

Instead, you need to spawn all the processes first (using something like `lists:map` to keep track of all the PIDs) and then wait for the results in a separate step.  Note that means you'll have to split the `ProcessID ! {self(),Number}` part from the `receive` part so that can be done in the first step, otherwise you're just spawning a bunch of idle processes.

So, something like:

```
Pids = lists:map( fun(N)-> ProcId = prime:start(N),
    io:fwrite("Calculating : procId=~p N=~p ~n",[ProcId,N]),
    ProcId end, NUMS).
lists:foreach( fun(ProcId) -> {N,RESULT}=prime:is_prime(ProcId),
    io:fwrite("Result procId=~p N=~p Result=~p ~n", [ProcId,N,RESULT]) end, Pids).

start(N)->spawn(?MODULE, forever_function, [N]).

forever_function(Number)->
    Result = is_prime(self(),2,Number),
    receive
        { From, get_result } -> From! {Number,Result},
        % unnecessary since we never call this Pid again, but do it anyway :)
        forever_function()
        % could also add more cases here to set the number
        % or even do a one-shot function like before
    end.

%multithreaded function
is_prime(ProcessID)->
    ProcessID ! {self(),get_result},
    receive
        RESULT->RESULT
    end.
```

Note: this is untested, so it may need some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm currently trying to implement your solution :-) The notation spawn(?MODULE, fun, args) was unknown to me. I'll validate your solution later.

Comment: ?MODULE is a built-in macro for the module name as an atom.  You could also use spawn(prime,Fun,Args) and it would be the same.

Comment: It is in some ways better to spawn a fun as you did originally as it saves you from exporting, and making visible, a function which is really only meant for internal use.